What is the best way to run a function after the DOM has loaded or view is rendered?
I have a usecase where I want to highlight the previously selected channel type(SMS or VOICE) option by user to recieve the OTP. I have already tried implementing ngAfterViewInit() like below.
############# Angular Component ####################
let contactMethod: string = 'sms';  //Previously selected phonetype by user

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.highlightSelectedMethod(this.contactMethod);

}
private highlightSelectedMethod(phoneType: string) {
  let selectedClass = 'selected';    //CSS class which highlights the selected phoneType
  let selectedPhoneType = document.getElementById(phoneType)   //When I log the selectedPhoneType, the value is turning out to be null which I think is becuase DOM is not loaded. 

if(selectedPhoneType){
  element.classlist.add(selectedClass);  //This if block is not running as selectedPhoneType is null when the code runs.
}

}
############   HTML  ############
<button id='sms'>sms</button>

<button id='voice'>voice</button>

What changes should I include to make sure that the CSS class gets added to the selected phoneType button after/once the page is rendered? I was of an impression that using ngAfterViewInit would solve the problem but document.getElementById() returns null even when the method is called from ngAfterViewInint?

On first sight it looks like your approach is not ideal. Some should have good reasons to use getElementById within angular! If you could provide a stackblitz I could try to understand what you want and be able to help you better.

You should use [ngClass] which can be used to add classes conditionally. Also prefer angular directives instead of JS or JQuery, do go through angular.dev for reference.
<button id='sms' [ngClass]="{'selected': contactMethod === 'sms'}">sms</button>

<button id='voice' [ngClass]="{'selected': contactMethod === 'voice'}">voice</button>


you can use angular ChangeDetectorRef
https://v17.angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef
